# Gradle build file with conf folder with properties not in jar but on classpath

Tags: java, gradle

Could you please share a build.gradle script example with configured folder "conf":

1. This folder including all containing files is packaged into zip file during "gradle distZip";
2. Files in this folder are on classpath (e.g. accessible to ClassLoader) in startscripts files (in bin folder);
3. These files also are on classpath when running gradle run, gradle build etc.

**Addition #1:**

I've done actions mentioned in answer pointed by @wakjah, files was copied to a zip file and was not put into jar during `gradle distZip`, this **covers my requirement #1**. But this folder is not on classpath in start scripts from `bin` folder (requirement #2 is **not covered**). Files are not on classpath when running `gradle clean run` (requirement #3 is **not covered**).

**Addition #2:**

I started sample project from scratch and with the help of **@wakjah** now I have:

1. Req #1: ok (directory `config` contains resource file), but this resource is also in `lib` folder.
2. Req #2: ok (directory `config` is on classpath in start script), but classpath additionally contains invalid folder `%APP_HOME%\lib\config`
3. Req #3: ok

Additionally, I tested 3 approaches of loading file contents (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862115/1828296)), method `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(name)` succeeded.

Added my sample project zip file here: http://rgho.st/8r2dJjSz7

**Addition #3**:

When I comment / remove in gradle script:

`dependencies {
  runtime files('src/dist/config')
}`

`lib/config` folder is not on CLASSPATH (it's ok), and resource file gets not copied to `lib` folder (it's ok). But resource file is failed to load both starting class main() method from Idea and running `gradle clean run` from command prompt. After `gradle clean distZip` and deploying (unpacking) application, resource gets loaded.

**Addition #4**:

After replacing

`dependencies {
  runtime files('src/dist/config')
}`

to
`tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
  classpath += files('src/dist/config')
}`
everything went fine, thanks, **@wakjah**!
There is one more issue, not mentioned in initial requirements: when I start this project inside Idea (not executing gradle run, but starting main() in class directly from Idea), file in `config` directory could not be loaded  using any of approaches mentioned earlier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028947/gradle-distzip-config-files

Comment: @wakjah I didn't found the question/anser you mentioned before I created my question, thanks for pointing. I'll check it.

Comment: Probably most robust way is: when performing distZip task (or related, f.e. distTar etc), do the following: 1) copy files by mask (or all) to a specified folder inside zip (tar.gz) file; 2). patch start script to add this folder to classpath. But I cannot get how it may be done, so gradle gurus help is very appreciated.

Comment: @lospejos: did you find a solution to the problem mentioned in addition #4? So can you have resources in `src/dist/config` which are on the classpath of IntelliJ, but not in the final jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned here [Gradle distZip config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028947/gradle-distzip-config-files) you can just add the folder `dist/config` to your `src` folder and it will be included by the `distZip` task automatically.

As for adding it to the runtime classpath, just add the folder as a dependency (see below).

Requirement #2 is a little harder, due to limitations with `startScripts`. This question has an answer that proposes a workaround, however: [Adding classpath entries using Gradle's Application plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10518603/adding-classpath-entries-using-gradles-application-plugin)

The following code collects all of the above:

```
// put config files in src/dist/config

dependencies {
  runtime files('src/dist/config')
}

startScripts {
  classpath += files('src/dist/XxxAPlaceHolderForAConfigxxX')
  doLast {
    def windowsScriptFile = file getWindowsScript()
    def unixScriptFile    = file getUnixScript()
    windowsScriptFile.text = windowsScriptFile.text.replace('%APP_HOME%\\lib\\XxxAPlaceHolderForAConfigxxX', '%APP_HOME%\\config')
    unixScriptFile.text  = unixScriptFile.text.replace('$APP_HOME/lib/XxxAPlaceHolderForAConfigxxX', '$APP_HOME/config')
  }
}
```

I have tested this and it appears to work. The correct classpath entries appear in both the run scripts and the command line used by gradle during the `run` task.

EDIT: In your comment you implied that you also want this to be available in the classpath of your build script. If that is the case, you need to add a buildscript dependency like this:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath files('src/dist/config')
  }
}
```

EDIT #2: In another comment you mention that adding the runtime dependency has the unintended consequence of producing an extra, invalid, entry in the start script classpath. You could fix this by just adding to the classpath of any `JavaExec` tasks, rather than using a dependency. So replace the `dependencies { runtime { ... } }` block with

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
  classpath += files('src/dist/config')
}
```

Comment: Well I have an error: `"A problem occurred evaluating root project 'report-rest-server-sparkjava'.
> Could not find method runtime() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler."`. I put `dependencies` block you mentioned into the root of my gradle script as well as inside `buildcript` block in my gradle script, but no luck. Gradle 2.14.1-rc-2

Comment: As I said before, I'm not an advanced Gradle user (that is sad), so please could you specify where exactly should I put your lines? Putting `startScripts` block in script "root" chain (not under some of closures) leads to: `Could not find method startScripts() for arguments [build_6f9g84j5bx1rq0giscgo9symy$_run_closure2@3419e23b] on root project '<my-project-name>' of type org.gradle.api.Project`

Comment: @lospejos You need to apply the `application` plugin in order to use `startScripts` -- see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: See my addition #2 in the question, we're almost done (notice the extra folder in start script classpath).

Comment: See additions #2 and #3

Comment: See addition #4. It's almost done, but there is one more issue. Anyway I believe you're completely answered my question (thanks again! :-) ) but if you're familiar with Idea, it could be nice to resolve the last issue (mentioned in addition #4).

Comment: @lospejos add this to your build.gradle will resolve your last issue:

   `sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "src/dist/config"`

Comment: @Budzu: your solution doesn't seem to work. I just end up with the resources back in the JAR where I don't want them.

Comment: @Pieter Did you try this? It looks like my previous command was missing the equals: `sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir="src/dist/config"`